# Can pooled standard deviation be used to determine sample size?

Tags: statistical-power, small-sample, pooling

I would like to use Minitab statistical software to determine a minimum sample size for precision (repeatability) testing. From casual observation, we know our allowable error is much wider than the error we have actually seen with the measurements and materials. To illustrate - I plugged in a sample standard deviation (n=3) from a file I had open, and it gives me a sample size of 2 for a 95% confidence interval.

And from my casual observation (eyeball, not mathematical :)) all our data sets seem to behave similarly - tightly clustered data points well within our allowable error.

Is it justifiable to use a pooled standard deviation from these data sets if I don't have one set of 30 replicates?

Many thanks!